# how to stop integer variable from taking double input (digits before decimal) and any other values?

Tags: c++, string, cin, stringstream

Why doesn't the `.fail()` work if I put any double or integer with character as input for the last vabiable e?

I have added some output pictures for this problem.

[image: Output sample]

Code:

```
int main() {
    string a,b,line;
    double c;
    int d,e;
    stringstream ss;
    getline(cin,line);
    ss<<line;
    ss>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
    cout<<"command: "<<a<<endl<<"arg1: "<<b<<endl<<"arg2: "<<c<<endl<<"arg3: "<<d<<endl<<"arg4: "<<e<<endl;
    if(ss.fail())
        cout<<"Error: invalid command"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"perfect"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

`>>` stops reading as soon as it finds input that cannot be parsed into whatever data type it's been told to read into. Input of 7.5 read into an `int` is a perfectly acceptable 7 and the .5, which cannot be part of an `int`,  is left in the stream to bedevil the next read from the stream. If OP had input 7.5 for the third argument (`int d`), the read of .5 into the fourth argument (`int e`) would have failed.

Ah. Totally neglected the How To Fix part.

My personal preference is to read all data in as a string and parse it myself. In this case I'd use [good ol' `strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), mostly because I haven't warmed to the idea of throwing exceptions over bad user input. Typos happen. They happen too often to be exceptional. Deal with it.

So we would read into `std::string e`, not `int e` and then...

```
char * endp; // strtol will point endp to character that ended the parsing. 
             // If that's not the end of the string there was stuff we couldn't parse
errno = 0; // clear the error code so we can catch an overflow error 
           // if the number parsed was too big
long num = std::strtol(e.c_str(), &endp, 10); // parse the string as a decimal number
if (*endp != '\0' || errno == ERANGE)
{
    // handle error. Abort, nag user and repeat, whatever
}
// use num
```

OP has added that they are not permitted to use C library calls. So be it. The [C++ library equivalent is std::stoi.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) My rant on exceptions above explains why I don't like this option, but here we go!

```
size_t end; 
int num = std::stoi(e, &end); // parse the string as a decimal number
if (end != e.length())
{
    // handle error. Abort, nag user and repeat, whatever
}
// use num
```

If it utterly fails to convert, `std::stoi` will throw `std::invalid_argument`. If the number provided was too big, it throws `std::out_of_range`, so either catch and handle the exceptions or let the program abort. Your call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. But I am not allowed to use C-library string-to-integer conversions(atoi, strtol, etc) and also anything other than C++ library type string. @user4581301

Comment: Unfortunate. Will edit with the `std::stoi` equivalent. Back in a few.

Answer (score 0):

```
template< typename From,typename To>
static inline bool superConvert(const From& fromVar,To& toVar)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<fromVar;
    ss>>toVar;
    if(ss.fail())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        From tempFrom;
        stringstream ss;
        ss<<toVar;
        ss>>tempFrom;
        if(tempFrom != fromVar)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

For integers this function works fine. Since it double check, the proper way is to use stdol but in case if it is not allowed u can use this.

```
int i;
bool convertSuccess = superConvert<string,int>("25",i);
cerr<<i;
```

Comment: Neat trick. You'll have some trouble with floating point on that, and I recommend fixing `From`'s type to `std::string` because a common use would be superConvert("25", somenumber); and that "25" will specialize the template for `char` arrays and `if(tempFrom != fromVar)` will always be true.

Comment: @user4581301 very thanks for pointing it out. First of all i created the function for converting from any type like time_t, int or any to any. May be in ur case 'superConvert<string,int>("25", somenumber);' will work.